# how to use a single command object in 2 different page without making it singleton

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I make transfer of a class object from one page to another in a jsp while doing server process too,

eg let be there a page1.jsp it have a commandObject page1 of a class Page

I then fill some of its value in page1.jsp,

I then want the same object to be transfered to another page say page2.jsp
and on that page I fill the remaining values of page1 object and then persist it to data base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't wan't to (or can't) use a Singleton bean, how about using the `request` or `session` scopes? They are custom-made for this kind of scenario.

> **3.5.4.2 Request scope**
>
> Consider the following bean
>   definition:

```
<bean id="loginAction" class="com.foo.LoginAction" scope="request"/>
```

> The Spring container
>   creates a new instance of the
>   `LoginAction` bean by using the
>   `loginAction` bean definition for each
>   and every HTTP request. That is, the
>   loginAction bean is scoped at the HTTP
>   request level. You can change the
>   internal state of the instance that is
>   created as much as you want, because
>   other instances created from the same
>   `loginAction` bean definition will not
>   see these changes in state; they are
>   particular to an individual request.
>   When the request completes processing,
>   the bean that is scoped to the request
>   is discarded.

---

> **3.5.4.3 Session scope**
>
> Consider the following bean
>   definition:

```
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session"/>
```

> The Spring container
>   creates a new instance of the
>   `UserPreferences` bean by using the
>   `userPreferences` bean definition for
>   the lifetime of a single HTTP Session.
>   In other words, the `userPreferences`
>   bean is effectively scoped at the HTTP
>   Session level. As with request-scoped
>   beans, you can change the internal
>   state of the instance that is created
>   as much as you want, knowing that
>   other HTTP Session instances that are
>   also using instances created from the
>   same userPreferences bean definition
>   do not see these changes in state,
>   because they are particular to an
>   individual HTTP Session. When the HTTP
>   Session is eventually discarded, the
>   bean that is scoped to that particular
>   HTTP Session is also discarded.

**Source:**

- [Request, session, and global session
  scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other)

Answer (score 2):

In the post method of your controller for page 1, add your command object to the model again and return the view name for page 2.

It sounds like you are describing a simple conversation workflow. If your workflow becomes more complex I recommend looking at [Spring Webflow](http://www.springsource.org/go-webflow2).