# Spring MVC 3.0 retain values on clicking of back hyperlink

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to Spring MVC. I have been given a task to submit a form. When I click submit on form page I am redirected to result page. On result page there is "Back" hyperlink.

When I am clicking this link I am getting the form bean back on form page but it does not have values retained.

Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the form values bound to a command object. Having the scope of the command object as `session` should help in retaining the value on going back to the page.

Eg: Check the `userPreferences` bean in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864275/344927)

Comment: Thanks stratwine...basically we are using load balancer in our project so I cannot save anything in session rather we have created hidden variables to save and send data